# “if the orientation … exceeds the defined orientation or non satisfaction”

Tags: passive-voice, run-on-sentences

I am struggling with the following sentence.

> In contrast, if the orientation and the maximum length of a rectangle
>   exceeds the defined orientation or **non satisfaction of the circle
>   constraint**, the cluster is discarded.

Is “non satisfaction” correct? Does it make sense in this sentence?

I feel that the highlighted phrase breaks the flow of the sentence as I am using *this and that exceeds that* and then I am directly using the noun *non satisfaction* to describe some other conditions which I need to express. Is the sentence ok?

Comment: Again, this is proofreading

Comment: FWIW, I'd write the bolded part as "does not satisfy the circle constraint" given my guess at what you're going for here, but FumbleFingers is right: this sort of thing isn't really what ELL is for. Check the [help page](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/asking) for more details on that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The close reason reads “Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.” This question does identify a specific source of concern, so why is it inappropriate?

Comment: @Gilles: I don't know enough about the context to have an opinion on whether "the circle constraint" is valid here, but fairly obviously OP's sentence needs something more than a direct replacement for "non satisfaction", as your own answer indicates. But I admit my closevote here was perhaps a little peremptory - I'd just done the same to two other questions from this same OP where the "proofreading" element was even more dominant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really suited for here but I'll answer it.

*non satifsfaction* doesn't really make English sense so I'd probably say. "does not satisfy the circle constraint"

You should be ok to describe another condition as long as you don't include too many.

Answer (score 0):

*Non-satisfaction* to express that a constraint is not satisfied is fine, though I'd prefer it hyphenated. Note that in everyday English, the noun to express that someone is not satisfied with something is *dissatisfaction*, and the corresponding adjective is *dissatisfied*, but these words are never used in the mathematical sense: a constraint can only be *unsatisfied* (which also exists in everyday English, but with a [different meaning](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/dissatisfied-unsatisfied/)) or *not satisfied*.

However, I don't understand the sentence. (Non-)satisfaction is boolean: it's either true or false. This isn't something that can be *exceeded*. What causes the cluster to be discarded? Is the non-satisfaction of the circle constraint related to the orientation? There is a similar problem with the maximum length: what does it mean for a length to exceed an orientation? Even the notion of an orientation exceeding a defined orientation is strange, but maybe that's because of my lack of familiarity with algorithmic geometry: I perceive orientation as something that can go round in a circle (or more in higher dimensions), not something that has an order relation.

Here is one way to write this sentence which is grammatical and comprehensible. Beware that I don't know if it expresses the right mathematical property, because I don't know what mathematical property you're trying to express.

> In contrast, if the orientation or the maximum length of a rectangle exceed the allowed range, or if the circle constraint is not satisfied, then the cluster is discarded.